# Why does this function converge point-wise to $0$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let
$$f_n(x) = \begin{cases}
\sin nx & 0 \leq x \leq \frac\pi n\\
0 & x \geq \frac\pi n
\end{cases}$$

Then my book says that $f_n \to f \equiv 0$ on the interval $[0, +\infty)$.
I don't understand why $0$ is included. I think that the interval of convergence should be $(0, +\infty)$ because $f(0) = 1$, not $0$. Is it an error in the book or have I misunderstood something? I think it's clear from the graph of $f_n$.

Comment: $\sin(0)=0{}{}{}$.

Comment: @AloizioMacedo But there will always be a point between $0$ and $\frac\pi n$ where the sine has a maximum, $1$.

Comment: Regarding your comment about there always being a point where sine has the value $1,$ note that the value of $f$ at a point $x$ is the limit (as $n \rightarrow \infty)$ of the values of $f_n$ at $x.$ So . . . picking $x>0,$ the value of $f(x)$ is $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}f_n(x),$ which equals $0$ when $x>0.$ That is, you pick $x$ first, then take the limit. In taking the limit, the maximums you're worried about get "squished closer to $0$" than $x$ is, for all sufficiently large values of $n.$

Comment: @rubik:Your argument is valid when discussing uniform convergence, where this would be one of the nice counter-examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are talking about *pointwise convergence*.

$$f_n(0)=\sin(n\cdot0)=0 \quad \forall n$$

Hence, $\lim f_n(0)=0$.

It doesn't matter what the function does near the point, as you implicitly assume in the comments. What matters is the values at the point you've fixed.

Comment: Ahh thanks. Your last sentence made me realize where I was wrong!

Answer (score 1):

Because $f_n(0) = \sin(n \cdot 0) = \sin(0) = 0$ for all $n$ we have $f_n(0) \to 0$. Suppose that $x > 0$. Then there exists some $N \geq 1$ with $x \geq \frac{\pi}{N}$. We  then have $x \geq \frac{\pi}{n}$ for all $n \geq N$. So for all $n \geq N$ we have $f_n(x) = 0$. Therefore $f_n(x) \to 0$.