# Why do we need both partial derivatives for $f(x, y)$ to guarantee that we can find min & max points?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

Given for example a function of 2 variables $z = f(x,y) = x^2 + xy + y^2$, I believe there are infinitely many directions on the $xy$ plane in which we could take partial derivatives (this could already be wrong...).

If we differentiate $z$ w.r.t $x$, we get $f_x = 2x+y$. If we set this partial derivative equal to zero, we get infinitely many solutions; namely it seems that for any value of $y$, we could find a value of $x$ such that at the point $(x,y)$ the slope in the direction of the $x$ axis would be zero.

However, only one of these infinitely many points is actually the minimum of the function.

But if we take the other partial derivative $f_y = 2y + x$ and set both of them equal to zero as a system of equations and solve that system, we will get our minimum point at $(0,0)$.

Why is that? Why is it that we need both partial derivatives and not fewer, or especially **more**?

EDIT: Just to make it clear, I'm wondering both why two PD's are the minimum, and also why they are guaranteed to be *enough* (as in, why don't we need 20 PD's?).

Comment: This question is unclear. IF the point is a maximum/minimum, then the partial derivatives (any) are $0$. The converse does not hold. If this question asked "Why are two PD being equal to $0$ throughout a domain sufficient to prove that the function is constant", then the question could admit a satisfying answer.

Comment: Note that, under mild assumptions, if both partial derivatives are $0$ at $ x $, then all directional derivatives at $ x $ must be $0$.

Comment: @AloizioMacedo, the question is unclear partly because of the confusion that prompted the question in the first place. By voting to close those kinds of questions you create a catch 22 whereby a whole subset of confused people asking legitimate clarifications are unable to do so because they don't understand the subject well enough to properly express their confusion.

Comment: @littleO, that's interesting and now makes sense to me in the context of Trevor's answer, thanks.

Comment: @jeremyradcliff I understand your point, but I don't think this is the case. There is a difference between a confusion which actually asks something (like this one http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1601095/why-does-this-function-converge-point-wise-to-0/), so one person can answer properly and the confused asker can verify whether what he was confused about is/is not true, and your question. Your question is "Why is it that we need both partial derivatives and not fewer, or especially more?" in order to determine maxima/minima, and as it is(...)

Comment: (...) it does not make sense. Note that all answers (including the accepted) boil down to explaining why two linearly independent vectors determine a plane, which is not your question at all. Well, maybe it is (since you've accepted it), but it should not be upon us the job of interpreting what was on a confused mind, it should be yours to clarify your confusion. Not only that, but having a confused ill-posed question makes for a poor future reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The analog of finding the tangent line for a function $f(x)$ is finding the tangent plane of $f(x,y)$. So just how one might find the max/min of $f(x)$ by finding where the tangent line is flat,  one can find the max/min of $f(x,y)$ by finding points where the tangent plane is flat (consider a "hill" in 3-d space to convince yourself of this).

To determine a plane in 3-d space, one needs at least two (linearly independent vectors) vectors. Therefore checking that vectors are flat in the $x$ and $y$ directions is enough to uniquely determine the entire tangent plane. If we only had one vector, there would be infinitely many planes which could go through it.

I believe one could take the directional derivatives of any two linearly independent unit vectors and check that they are zero to determine if the tangent plane is flat. However the $x$ and $y$ directions tend to be the most natural.

Comment: This makes perfect sense, it's exactly the kind of insight i was looking for. Thank you.

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 1):

The following picture shows why we need two directions:

[image]

You see that the only minimum point is the red dot. But if we only find the derivative along, for example, $y$-direction, we get the whole bottom curve, which are minimums along the cross-sections parallel to the $y$-axis.

The reason why we don't need more directions is because the directional derivative can be represented by the derivative in $x$ and $y$ directions. So if these two are $0$'s, the other derivatives should also be $0$'s.

Comment: Your graph actually makes it easier for me to understand what's going on, thank you.

Comment: @jeremyradcliff: Glad to know that.